# Is it possible to bypass a "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget" exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

I want to move an Image (my hero) in a Grid of Images. When I remove the corridor it moves to and place the hero Image there, the code executes fine (the hero is the only unique image in the grid). But when I place a corridor Image on the hero's previous location, I receive the above mentioned error. I understand that it is because I have like 50 other corridor Images as Children in the Grid with the name "corridorImg".

```
int newTileIndex = Image_Grid2.Children.IndexOf(heroImg) + map.mapWidth - 1;
int currentTileIndex = Image_Grid2.Children.IndexOf(heroImg);

Image_Grid2.Children.RemoveAt(currentTileIndex);
Image_Grid2.Children.RemoveAt(newTileIndex);

// Tried to solve issue by creating new Image by using clone of the corridor Image, but same exception
Image oldTileImage = new Image();
oldTileImage = corridorImg;             

Image_Grid2.Children.Insert(currentTileIndex, oldTileImage);
Image_Grid2.Children.Insert(newTileIndex, heroImg);
```

Comment: Remember I told you you should be using MVVM for this? then you would be manipulating simple classes and properties instead of having to struggle with the complexity of the Visual Tree...

Comment: What platform is this? WPF? WinForms? Silverlight?

Comment: @jrummell: Platform is WPF

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @HighCore that you should use MVVM for this.

Your specific issue though is that you didn't actually clone the Image, you just made a new one and then overwrote the variable it was assigned to. In your second-to-last line, you're re-inserting the original corridorImg, you're just calling it oldTileImage. To truly clone the Image, you need to copy its properties over. If you're using image sources, that would look like:

```
Image corridorImgClone = new Image();
corridorImgClone.Source = corridorImg.Source;
```